I think linguistics is a pseudoscience, full of lies and misinformation. Why can't this opinion be expressed here?
Almost EVERYTHING in linguistics is either an outright lie ("pre-fortis clipping") or full of  vague, misleading claims.  Am I banned from asking questions that expose the complete fraud linguistics is?  Please remove the ban on my asking questions and deal with them objectively.  I am asserting that if at all "pre-fortis clipping" occurs, it is negligible in flowing speech.  Surely, we need an objective answer to this question?  or do participants want the soothing lies of linguistics be sacrosanct?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th


I am asserting that if at all "pre-fortis clipping" occurs, it is negligible in flowing speech. Surely, we need an objective answer to this question?

Sure, that's a fine question to ask. It's something people have researched, and continue to research, and we can get interesting, more-or-less objective answers to it.

Am I banned from asking questions that expose the complete fraud linguistics is?

This part is the problem. Inflammatory questions that seem more focused on ranting than on polite discussion don't tend to go over well. People are volunteering their time and energy here because we enjoy talking about linguistics, but very few people enjoy just being shouted at.

I think linguistics is a pseudoscience, full of lies and misinformation. Why can't this opinion be expressed here?

Because the social contract of this place requires respecting others and their positions. It's not questioning pre-fortis clipping that's causing the problem, it's the aggressive and hostile tone you're doing it in.

Tone is in the eye of the beholder.  That listeners tell "beat" apart from "bead" mainly through "pre-fortis shortening is an arrant lie.  Linguistics is almost completely a set of lies, misinformation, half-truths etc..  I'll be more than happy to demolish linguistics in a respectful tone @draconis

"schwa" is a fiction.  How do you think I "enjoy" reading about "schwa"?  people should emulate Ben Shapiro "facts don't care about your feelings". @draconis

@SK You're welcome to not read about schwa, then, and you're welcome to question any part of linguistics orthodoxy in a respectful tone. I certainly agree that a worrying amount of syntax is more concerned about being compatible with Chomsky's theories than the actual evidence. But one of the conditions of using this site is being respectful, and if you don't do that, the automated systems will prevent you from asking more questions. (Which is what happened here.)

If being "respectful" is detected by systems - that is not good.  Most SE sites have the feel of a chain gang with humor being punishable severely.   most Moderators can transition straight to prison guards with very little training.  I think it is the infantile downvotes that are causing me a problem.  If I try to delete the Q, the system says "you can't delete an answered question" @draconis

@SK That's by design. See the article Dannii linked.

@SK Calling people "infantile" and "moronic" may not be detected by the automatic systems, but the mods do notice, and we do take action. Please step up your respectfulness.

Arrant lies are posted decorously.  But questioning them "indecorously" leads to censorship, with no recourse.  This is intellectual Stalinism @curiousdannii

@SK You don't seem to understand why people use this site. We're not public servants or paid employees, we're volunteering our time and effort because we enjoy discussing these things. We don't enjoy being shouted at, and we have no obligation to do it, because again, none of us are being paid for this.

So I am being censored because I am spoiling the fun everybody is having.  spreading falsehoods.  The mods are pretending not to know what they are doing with me.. @draconis

@SK Again, we're all volunteers here, not civil servants. There's no government muzzling you, just volunteers who aren't interested in being shouted at. If you want to question the acoustic reality of pre-fortis clipping, go right ahead. But we have rules for a reason, and it's because the site depends on volunteers who aren't going to stick around if it just means being shouted at incessantly. That's the source of the downvotes, which triggered an automatic question ban.

You are repeatedly using the gratuitous false insult that I am "shouting at" anybody.  At other fora, I have found a mistake in the Oxford English Dictionary just following my instincts.  Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?   @draconis

I don't care if the mods volunteer at the local fire service or take care of widows and orphans.  They are subjecting me to Stalinist censorship - that is ALL I care about. @draconis

@SK If you go to your local grocery store and start screaming at people, they'll ask you to leave. If you go into a restaurant and take your pants off, same thing. Or if you go into a public swimming pool with an open wound. Places having rules you have to follow isn't "Stalinism". We're not the government, and you have no fundamental right to use any particular website. You're welcome to use this site if you're respectful and polite about it. Otherwise, you're not. It's as simple as that.

@draconis - Thanks for exposing yourself. your analogies for my behavior are leprous.  I don't WANT to be around people whose hearts harbor such ugliness.  Have fun with "pre-fortis clipping"
